# Is there a limit on how many factions I can join?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok so I've been playing skyrim elder scrolls v and I am addicted. I know that if I become a vampire I can't become a werewolf. Is there any other restrictions on joining factions or a limit on how many factions I can join?

Answer (score 3):

There are no limit to the number of factions you can join, and you can join all the factions, bar Both the Stormcloak **and** the imperials, and the Dawnguard **and** the Clan. In each case you can join one or the other. 
[Here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Factions_(Skyrim)) is a list of joinable factions. Some factions can be invalidated by the following:

- Greybeards:

  > Killing Paarthurnax
- Dark Brotherhood:

  > - Destroying the dark brotherhood
- Imperial Legion:

  > Joining the stormcloaks
- Stormcloaks:

  > - Joining the legion
- Dawngaurd:

  > -Accepting the gift in "A new order"
- Volkihar Clan:

  > -Rejecting the gift in "The new order"

These will invalidate joining these, so if you want to join the Dawngaurd:

> you have to refuse the gift.

Comment: You’ll effectively get kicked out of the Blades for not doing your first spoiler. You also lose your chance to join the Coven of Namira if you refuse when offered.

Comment: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Paarthurnax_(Quest) They don't kick you out so much as refuse to help you until you do it. Note from wiki: "There is no actual way of denying the request of the Blades, other than simply abstaining from doing it."